# NameError: name 'current_portfolio' is not defined

Tags: python, algorithm, quantopian

I am getting NameError: name 'current_portfolio' is not defined

```
def initialize(context):
context.sym = symbol('xxx')
context.i = 0


def handle_data(context, data):

context.i += 1
if context.i < 60:
    return

sma1 = data.history(context.sym, 'price', 5, '1d').mean()
sma2 = data.history(context.sym, 'price', 60, '1d').mean()

current_price = data[context.sym].price
**current_position = current_portfolio.positions[symbol('xxx')].amount**
cash = context.portfolio.cash
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: ...can you show us where you define `current_portfolio` so we can help you?

Comment: I have edited the question with extended code. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not define current_portfolio anywhere in this code, from what is shown at least.

In order to call current_portfolio it must be defined somewhere above where you call it.

This is why you are getting the "not defined" error.