# NameError: name 'XXX' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, function, nameerror

I have a function `def viterbi()`. One of the input variabless is `sequence`. Later on in the function I am calling `sequence`. However, by doing so, it returns:

```
NameError: name 'sequence' is not defined
```

Here is my function:

```
def viterbi(sequence, p_start=None, p_trans=None, p_stop=None, p_emiss=None):


length = len(sequence)
num_states = len(p_start)
best_path = []

# trellis to store Viterbi scores
trellis = np.full([length, num_states], -np.inf)

# backpointers to backtrack
backpointers = -np.ones([length, num_states], dtype=int)

trellis[0] = p_start + p_emiss[obs2i[sequence[0].obs]] # log(viterbi(1,ck))

# Fill the remaining columns with transition probabilities
for i in range(1, length):
  matrix_product = p_trans + trellis[i - 1]
  backpointers[i] = [max_index(el) for el in matrix_product]
  max_over_c_l = [max(el) for el in matrix_product]
  trellis[i] = max_over_c_l + p_emiss[obs2i[sequence[i].obs]]

# Compute the maximum probability with end probabilities
ending_probabilities = p_stop + trellis[-1]
final_backpointer = max_index(ending_probabilities)
best_score = max(ending_probabilities)

# Compute the best path by backtracking
for seq in range(0,length):
    best_path.append(backpointers[seq][max_index(trellis[seq])])
best_path.append(final_backpointer)

return (best_score, best_path)
```

I have looked at similar questions, but none seem to deal with the same problem as I do:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50951795/intinput-error-nameerror-name-is-not-defined), there is no input variable in the function.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920320/python-nameerror-name-xxx-is-not-defined), a variable that is created in the function is called outside of the function.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60022844/nameerror-name-current-portfolio-is-not-defined), the variable is simply not defined.

What confuses me is that the variable `sequence` is an input to the function. Therefore, I would expect that the function knows what `sequence` is. Also, when I initialize the variable `length` within the function, it does not return an error.

Who can tell me what is going on here? And what can I do to overcome this problem?

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: set sequence=none

Comment: On the line: trellis[0] = p_start + p_emiss[obs2i[sequence[0].obs]] @IlknurMustafa

Comment: @DeV, where should I put that?

Comment: Maybe try printing the results because despite using it before you're not getting the error. Try printing after each line and make sure your object is a class that has the function obs